# Laravel request fullUrlWithQuery returns http instead of https

Tags: php, laravel

This is my code,

```
<button
    class='ml-3 btn btn-success'
    onclick="exportSheet(this, '{{ request()->fullUrlWithQuery([ 'export' => 1 ]) }}')"
>
    Export
</button>
```

This, for some reason, returns `http://example.com` instead of `https://example.com`. The weird part is `request()->url()` returns https.

```
<form method="get" action="{{ request()->url() }}"></form>
```

I have forced https scheme in `AppServiceProvider`:

```
if (App::environment('production')) {
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

What is going on?

Comment: Strive to discover difference. There seems to be no difference: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L130 AND https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/9.x/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L106

Comment: @dbf No it https. Why else would `request()->url()` have https but `request()-> fullUrlWithQuery()` won't? This whole situation doesn't make any sense to me haha.

Comment: Hmm I see, what does `request()->isSecure()` and `request()->getScheme()` return?

Comment: Okidoki, I did a stacktrace. Both `request()->url()` and `request()->fullUrlWithQuery()` is always going to be `$this->url()` or `$this->fullUrl()` where `fullUrl()` always calls `url()`. `url()` always calls `getUri()` which always calls `getSchemeAndHttpHost()` which always calls `getScheme()` which always and ends with `isSecure()`. So this difference should never exist.

Comment: What's the exact Laravel version you are using?

Answer (score 1):

in my case my app was running behind litespeed proxy with laravel:octane and swoole.

Request::fullUrlWithQuery() was returning http:// instead of https://.

After updating the TrustProxies middleware as shown below and

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Fideloper\Proxy\TrustProxies as Middleware;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TrustProxies extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The trusted proxies for this application.
     *
     * @var array|string|null
     */
    protected $proxies = [
        '192.168.1.1',
        '127.0.0.1',
        '*',
    ];

    /**
     * The headers that should be used to detect proxies.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    protected $headers = Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_FOR | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PORT | Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_PROTO;
}
```

```
php artisan octane:reload
```

everything was fine.

detailed information is [here](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies)